# Validating Form Field against MYSQL database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, forms

I am trying to do what I thought would be a simple task, but it has turned out to be rather difficult.  All I want to do is provide a 1 field form allow the user to type in a unique id and hit submit.  If the unique id matches one of the ids in the database then they are directed to a page.  If the id doesn't match I want it to tell "Id doesn't match, try again" or something like that.

I have looked at countless tutorials involving login forms, but that is a bit more than what I need and every time I have tried to simplify it to be what I need, it doesn't work.  I have tried a ton of different code.  Here is what I currently have.

UPDATED CODE:

```
<form name="enterclient" method="post">
<label for="clientid">Enter your client id</label><br />
<input name="clientid" id="clientid"><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>

<?php global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();
$host = 'myhost';
$username = 'myuser';
$pass = 'mypass';
$database = 'mydb';
$link = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$pass, $database);

$clientid = $_REQUEST['clientid'];

if ($link) {

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {   
    if (empty ($clientid)) {
    //if username field is empty echo below statement
        echo "you must enter your unique username <br />";
    }
    $query = "SELECT * FROM wp_locations WHERE client = '". mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$clientid) ."'" ;
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Unable to query");
    $option = "";
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    $option .= "<option value='{$row['client']}'>{$row['client']}</option>";
    }
}

else {   
}//close else

if ($result) {
print $option;
    echo "query successful";
    header('location: http://www.google.com');
}
else {
    echo"query fail";
}


}//end of initial if $db_found

else {
    print "Database NOT Found ";
}

// disconnect from the database
mysql_close();?>
```

**UPDATED OUTPUT:**
When I got to the initial page, it still says "query fail" and I am guessing it is because the $clientid doesnt have a value yet.

When I enter something in the box no matter what it is, it returns "query successful".  I would like it to only return successful if the input matches the one of the database values.

IF I enter a value I know matches a database value, it gives me a list of that database value however many times it exists, and says query successful.

It is important to note that the redirect seems to never work.

Comment: you are mixing mysql with mysqli

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: you have mysql_connect($host,$username,$pass); and later using $result = mysqli_query($query); so the query will not work u need to check http://in1.php.net/mysqli_connect

Comment: Using `mysqli_*` you can use `if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)` to check for a match; and don't mix your SQL functions, they basically don't mix ;-) `mysqli_*` and `mysql_*` is a lethal combination <=(quick tutorial).

Comment: you should put your query script inside of your `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {` statement that way it only executes if the form has been submitted. And clean code and indention can show a lot of mistakes!

Comment: okay I changed $result = mysqli_query($query) or die("Unable to query"); to just regular mysql_query...  and now when the page loads it says "query successful", however, when I type anything into the field and hit submit i get "query fail".

Comment: It's doing its job then. It's as if nothing was found. (*query fail*) What was your expected result? If you want to prevent that, check for an empty field also.

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$string) you have only $string no connection parameter.

Comment: Okay I added mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$string) as suggested.  But when I enter something in the field and hit submit its still saying "query fail".

My expected result would be if the value typed in the input matches one of the variables in the db for client id that it sets the input field to a variable and moves on to the redirect page.

Comment: please post ur updated code in the question.

Comment: Did you not change **all** => `mysql_` to `mysqli_` <= ? Plus, in doing that you risk in having add some parameters.

Comment: Do i even need to change the one on the fetch_array?  I thought mysql_fetch_array was depreciated?

Comment: Okay updated code has been posted.  Result is "query fail" until i enter a value in the box and hit submit, then it changes to "query successful" even if I type in a value that doesnt match the database...

Comment: New code posted in question results in "query fail" on page load and "Unable to query" whenever I enter something in the box and click submit.

Comment: What is the `get_currentuserinfo();` function supposed to do? Plus, you haven't changed your `mysql_close();?>` to `mysqli_close($link);`. Also, `$current_user` is a stray variable. What is that supposed to be referencing? A lot of things in your code doesn't add up. You're best to start over and find yourself a working demo of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: the current posted code in the question is mostly working.  The only issue with it is that it returns "query successful" even if the value entered isn't an EXACT match to the database variable.  In fact, it returns "query successful" no matter what I enter in the field.  

$current_user is a remnant of some coding that tied an older file to a wp_database.  Its existence, while unnecessary, doesn't effect the rest of the code.  To prove such, I have commented it out and opened the page.  Same result...

Comment: So the only question that remains is, why is the code returning "query successful" when I have entered a value that doesn't match any value in the database.

Comment: @Chris sorry for the late reply. See the comment under my answer as to why you are getting `query successful`

Answer (score 0):

Look at your code after it is indented:

```
if ($db_found) {
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        //if username field is empty echo below statement
        if (empty ($clientid)){
            echo "you must enter your unique username <br />";
        }
    } else {   
        $query = "SELECT * FROM wp_locations WHERE client = '". mysqli_real_escape_string($clientid) ."'" ;
        $result = mysqli_query($query) or die("Unable to query");
        $option = "";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $option .= "<option value='{$row['client']}'>{$row['client']}</option>";
        }
    }
    if ($result){
        print $option;
        echo "query successfull";
        header('location: http://www.google.com');
    } else {
        echo"query fail";
    }
//end of initial if $db_found
} else {
    print "Database NOT Found ";
}
```

Now you can easily see that you only form the query if the form is not submitted. I am pretty sure that is not what you want. Is it????

You want similiar to:

```
if ($db_found) {
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        //if username field is empty echo below statement
        if (empty ($clientid)){
            echo "you must enter your unique username <br />";
        }
        $query = "SELECT * FROM wp_locations WHERE client = '". mysqli_real_escape_string($clientid) ."'" ;
        $result = mysqli_query($query) or die("Unable to query");
        $option = "";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $option .= "<option value='{$row['client']}'>{$row['client']}</option>";
        }
        if ($result){
            print $option;
            echo "query successfull";
            header('location: http://www.google.com');
        } else {
            echo"query fail";
        }
    }
//end of initial if $db_found
} else {
    print "Database NOT Found ";
}
```

**BUT** you still have problems of using `mysql_*` mixed with `mysqli_*` extensions use only `mysqli_*` you then need to look at the functions to use the correct parameters for instance mysqi_query now takes at minimum two parameters. Have a look at these references:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

**SOLUTION:** below should be the working solution I have not tested this code but it should be what you are looking for. Normally I do not go to this extent to do someone elses work, but I felt generous this morning.

```
<form name="enterclient" method="post">
<label for="clientid">Enter your client id</label><br />
<input name="clientid" id="clientid"><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>

<?php

global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$host = 'myhost';
$username = 'myuser';
$pass = 'mypass';
$database = 'mydb';
//connect to MySQL database
$link = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$pass, $database);
//if not connected kill page and throw error
if (!$link) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}
//check if form submitted and clientid is not empty
if(isset($_POST['clientid']) && !empty($_POST["clientid"]))){
    //escape clientid to use in query
    $clientid = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['clientid']);
    //form query
    $query = "SELECT client FROM wp_locations WHERE client = '$clientid'";
    //run query on server and if not successful then kill page and throw error
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    //set variable to fill with database data and print
    $option = "";
    //check if any rows were returned from database
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
        //for each row that was returned set $row equal to an array of values for that row
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            //set $option with values from the database as there is only possible one value use = instead of .=
            $option = "<option value='{$row['client']}'>{$row['client']}</option>";
        }
        //print the option
        print $option;
        //show that the query was successful
        print "query successful";
        //set redirect to happen in 5 seconds
        $redirect = "http://www.google.com";
        $wait = 5; // seconds to wait
        print "You will be redirected to $redirect in $wait seconds."
        print "<span style='display:none'><meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='$wait; URL=$redirect'></span>";
    } else {
        //show that the query was successful but that the client was not found
        print "query successful but client not found please try again";
    }
    //free the MySQL result set
    mysqli_free_result($result);
} else {
    //the form was either not submitted or submitted with an empty value.
    print "Please complete and submit the form above.";
}
//close the connection to the MySQL server
mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: I looked at your suggestions and attempted to implement them.  I have updated the question with the new code I am using.  Now when I go to the page it initially says "query fail" and then when I type anything in the box and click submit it returns "Unable to query".  Thoughts?

Comment: The current code in the question appears to be borderline functional.  The only issues remain is that it is giving query success even if value from input doesn't match a database value and also the redirect never works.

Comment: your `query successfull` returns on checking the return of `mysqli_query` have a look at the reference here: http://us2.php.net/mysqli_query you should use `mysqli_num_rows` to check if any rows were returned. As far as the redirect, you need to read up on the header function: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php Specifically `Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.` You should use references frequently when debugging in doing so you would see why the redirect is not working yourself.

Comment: Could you give an example of how you would implement the mysqli_num_rows piece?

Comment: I feel like the problem lies in the if statement containing $result.  What I am trying to do is say, if (typed value = a client value from the db) then run the function.  If it doesnt match else{ echo "failed"}  Any idea what I could change the if statement to to make that work?

Comment: @Chris please see my edited answer for the solution.